# How do i align photos

Tags: html, css

I've tried to play with the % but the photos keep clipping each other instead of sitting side by side.Im just trying to get each photo to sit next to each other horizontally.Any ideas on what im doing wrong?
 Ps im new to coding so if this is a easy fix my bad

Snippet:

```css
body{
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 max-width: 750px;
}

li{
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
   <li>Anime</li>
 <ol>
  <li>
        <a href="http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page"> 
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RmlPLKy.jpg" 
            alt="See you in space cowboy..." width="500" hight="500"
                >Cowboy Bebop</li>`   
    
                                                                                    
 

      <li> 
     <a href="http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page"> 
      <img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/291ca87d855bf9fce76a148b3ebbf262/tumblr_n4ygiesFsG1sji00bo1_1280.jpg" 
       alt="Best Alchemist" width="500" hight="500"
         >Full Metal Alchemist</li>

 
    <li> 
         <a href="http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_Wing"> 
          <img src="http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/gundam-wing-deathscythe-wallpaper-2.jpg" alt="Death Scythe" width="500" hight="500"
                     >Gundam Wing</li>

  

   
  

    <li>
          <a href="http://champloo.wikia.com/wiki/Samurai_Champloo_Wiki"> 
           <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/26/5b/c7/265bc7d70425503b0e9c9c3226b4bfcd.jpg" 
             alt="Jin Fuu Mugen" width="500" hight="500"
                 >Samurai Champloo</a></li>
 </ol></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a `display: flex;` on the `ol`. You also did not close the `<a>` in your list making it invalid markup.

```css
.uno-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.uno-list li {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.uno-list a {
  display: block;
}

.uno-list img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
  <ol class="uno-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RmlPLKy.jpg" alt="See you in space cowboy..." width="500" hight="500"> Cowboy Bebop</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page">
        <img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/291ca87d855bf9fce76a148b3ebbf262/tumblr_n4ygiesFsG1sji00bo1_1280.jpg" alt="Best Alchemist" width="500" hight="500"> Full Metal Alchemist
      </a>
    </li>


    <li>
      <a href="http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_Wing">
        <img src="http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/gundam-wing-deathscythe-wallpaper-2.jpg" alt="Death Scythe" width="500" hight="500"> Gundam Wing
      </a>
    </li>


    <li>
      <a href="http://champloo.wikia.com/wiki/Samurai_Champloo_Wiki">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/26/5b/c7/265bc7d70425503b0e9c9c3226b4bfcd.jpg" alt="Jin Fuu Mugen" width="500" hight="500">Samurai Champloo</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. The only thing is now the sizes have reverted back to their original sizes. I've played with the width and height settings but they wont go back to being the same size like before. Any suggestions?

Comment: @HowardJackson you are welcome! In your original post there are no sizes for `width` and `height` for the images. If that is what you need you could just post them in comment here or add it to the original post and I'll have a look at it. Or just let me know how you want it.

Comment: Yes I orignally put the height and width into the HTML as  width="500" height="300" but it wont change for some reason.

Comment: @HowardJackson Oh my bad I didn't see it. That is because of the `.uno-list img` is set to `width: 100%;`, but given your max-width on the body there is a problem. We set the `li` to be `25%`of `750px` and if you want to contain the image inside of the `li` so it does not overlap each other. If you want the images to be `500px` wide we have to change a few things?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see your images horizontally sitting next to each other you shouldn't use very short width like you did (`max-width: 750px;`) and you don't need to place it in a list. So here is your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    a{
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="uno">
        <a href="http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page">
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RmlPLKy.jpg" 
            alt="See you in space cowboy..." width="500" hight="500"
                >Cowboy Bebop</a>
     <a href="http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page"> 
      <img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/291ca87d855bf9fce76a148b3ebbf262/tumblr_n4ygiesFsG1sji00bo1_1280.jpg" 
       alt="Best Alchemist" width="500" hight="500"
         >Full Metal Alchemist</a>

         <a href="http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_Wing"> 
          <img src="http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/gundam-wing-deathscythe-wallpaper-2.jpg" alt="Death Scythe" width="500" hight="500"
                     >Gundam Wing</a>

          <a href="http://champloo.wikia.com/wiki/Samurai_Champloo_Wiki"> 
           <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/26/5b/c7/265bc7d70425503b0e9c9c3226b4bfcd.jpg" 
             alt="Jin Fuu Mugen" width="500" hight="500"
                 >Samurai Champloo</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<body>
```

Comment: you should really introduce a `clearfix` doing this example.